# Issue with python's string find method returning -1

Tags: python, string, find, tokenize, lowercase

I'm trying to write a function that takes a string and returns the token positions. The function works fine when `tokens = query_string.split()` but if I try to use the string lower method, as shown in my code below, my first tuple returns as `[(-1, 2), (5, 6), (8, 8), (10, 13)]` rather than the desired output of `[(0, 3), (5, 6), (8, 8), (10, 13)]`

The string I used for testing is 'This is a test'.

```
def token_position_list(query_string):
    """
    :param query_string: a string representing a query
    :return: a list of tuples, where each tuple holds the start and end positions of each token
    """
    token_positions = []
    tokens = query_string.lower().split()
    current_position = 0
    for token in tokens:
        start_position = query_string.find(token, current_position)
        end_position = start_position + len(token) - 1
        token_positions.append((start_position, end_position))
        current_position = end_position + 1
    return token_positions
```

Can anyone explain to me why adding lower does this and how I could fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. We do not write answers here that "find the bug"; we require a **specific** question - which will come out of your best attempt to [understand](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/) and [locate](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05) a specific problem, and showcase it in a [mre]. A question that is suitable for Stack Overflow is one where you have already figured out the **specific part** of the code that does something different from what you expect (and you should concretely *expect something*), and don't understand why.

Comment: "why adding lower does this" - well, did you try to check, step by step, what happens when the code runs? For example, for the given input of `This is a test`, what do you think should be the result of `query_string.lower().split()`? What result do you get, if you explicitly check? Is it what you expected? What do you expect will be the value of `token` the first time through the `for token in tokens:` loop? What do you think should happen, if you try to find the string `this` inside the string `This is a test`? Why?

Answer (score 0):

All your tokens are lowercase, but `query_string` is still mixed-case. So it won't find the token if the original string has any uppercase letters in that token.

You should convert `query_string` to lowercase and process that.

```
def token_position_list(query_string):
    """
    :param query_string: a string representing a query
    :return: a list of tuples, where each tuple holds the start and end positions of each token
    """
    token_positions = []
    query_string = query_string.lower()
    tokens = query_string.split()
    current_position = 0
    for token in tokens:
        start_position = query_string.find(token, current_position)
        end_position = start_position + len(token) - 1
        token_positions.append((start_position, end_position))
        current_position = end_position + 1
    return token_positions
```

Comment: Omg thank you, this is my first time using find in python and I got so caught up on thinking I was probably using it wrong that I didn't see that. Thank you so much!